# "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid left-hand side in assignment"

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to run the calculator javascript app that i have created but am encountering a left hand side error no matter what I do some help correcting this issue would be greatly appreciated. It seems that there is some kind of syntax error but I have reviewed my code multiple times and can't find the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="main">
      <div class="calculator">
        <div class="display"></div>
        <div class="clearButton">Clear</div>
        <div class="deleteButton">Delete</div>
        <div class="btn">0</div>
        <div class="btn">1</div>
        <div class="btn">2</div>
        <div class="btn">3</div>
        <div class="btn">4</div>
        <div class="btn">5</div>
        <div class="btn">6</div>
        <div class="btn">7</div>
        <div class="btn">8</div>
        <div class="btn">9</div>
        <div class="btn">+</div>
        <div class="btn">-</div>
        <div class="btn">*</div>
        <div class="btn">/</div>
        <div class="btn">=</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```js
const calculator = function () {
  const displayText = document.getElementById("display");
  const problem = [];

  const math = function (buttonValue) {
    problem.push(buttonValue);

    console.log(problem);

    if (buttonValue === "=") {
      const result = eval(problem.join(""));
      console.log(result);
      displayText.textContent = result;
      problem.length = 0;
      problem.push(result);
    }
  };

  const btn0 = document.getElementById("0");
  btn0.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "0";
    math(btn0.textContent);
  });

  const btn1 = document.getElementById("1");
  btn1.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "1";
    math(btn1.textContent);
  });

  const btn2 = document.getElementById("2");
  btn2.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "2";
    math(btn2.textContent);
  });

  const btn3 = document.getElementById("3");
  btn3.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "3";
    math(btn3.textContent);
  });

  const btn4 = document.getElementById("4");
  btn4.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "4";
    math(btn4.textContent);
  });

  const btn5 = document.getElementById("5");
  btn5.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "5";
    math(btn5.textContent);
  });

  const btn6 = document.getElementById("6");
  btn6.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "6";
    math(btn6.textContent);
  });

  const btn7 = document.getElementById("7");
  btn7.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "7";
    math(btn7.textContent);
  });

  const btn8 = document.getElementById("8");
  btn8.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "8";
    math(btn8.textContent);
  });

  const btn9 = document.getElementById("9");
  btn9.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "9";
    math(btn9.textContent);
  });

  const btnPlus = document.getElementById("+");
  btnPlus.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "+";
    math(btnPlus.textContent);
  });

  const btnMinus = document.getElementById("-");
  btnMinus.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "-";
    math(btnMinus.textContent);
  });

  const btnMultiply = document.getElementById("*");
  btnMultiply.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "*";
    math(btnMultiply.textContent);
  });

  const btnDivide = document.getElementById("/");
  btnDivide.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent += "/";
    math(btnDivide.textContent);
  });

  const btnEqual = document.getElementById("=");
  btnEqual.addEventListener("click", function () {
    math(btnEqual.textContent);
  });

  const btnClear = document.querySelector(".clearButton");
  btnClear.addEventListener("click", function () {
    displayText.textContent = "";
    problem.length = 0;
  });

  const btnDelete = document.querySelector(".deleteButton");
  btnDelete.addEventListener("click", function () {
    problem.pop();
    displayText.textContent = problem.join("");
  });
};

calculator();
```

the html code. Can someone help me with this CSS problem?

Comment: That's not the error being produced when running this code snippet.  Can you indicate specifically which line of code is producing this error, and/or produce a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the error?

Comment: `eval(problem.join(""));` would appear to be your problem. That's [not how to do math in a calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11422513/1048572).

Answer (score 0):

You should not add the `=` sign to the array, as that causes it to no longer be a valid expression after joining.

```js
if (buttonValue === "=") {
  // ...
} else problem.push(buttonValue);
```