# How make query in JSON with variable substitution

Tags: javascript

I have JSON file like this (example):

```
{
"deecracks": [
{
"layercodename": "osm",
"layername": "Open Street Map",
},
{
"layercodename": "olen",
"layername": "tracks",
}
],
      
"theboomtownrats": [
{
"layercodename": "kuku",
"layername": "Open Street Map",
},
{
"layercodename": "olen",
"pathto": "rerere.json",
}
]
}
```

I can get value what me need:

```
var megatest = data.theboomtownrats[0].layercodename;
```

This will be ***kuku***

But ***theboomtownrats*** or ***deecracks*** or other value like this contain in variable.
If i in code write just ***data.theboomtownrats[0].layercodename*** all is work, but if i do like this:

```
var testmega = `'data.' + ${artist} + '[0].layercodename'`
```

or just use concatenation text and variable i get just same string in var testmega.

Its possible - substitution value of variable in query? If possible - how?

p.s. I found - this can make over the eval() and this work, but people say it's not safe, and must do over the function, but i have failute with this.

[Evaluate an Equation in Javascript, without eval()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11422513/evaluate-an-equation-in-javascript-without-eval)

[image: Exmaple from console]

Comment: https://youmightnotneed.com/lodash#get looking for somethig like this?

Comment: You can [use bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors), and pass in the variable name: `data[artist][0].layercodename`

Comment: You can enumerate the keys of an object with Object.keys.  In your code, `Object.keys(data)` would equal `[“deecracks”, “theboomtownrats”]`

Comment: Can you please format your question better? Both code and text are hard to read. Take a look at some highly rated JS questions for examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bracket notation with javascript objects and pass a variable to them.

So instead of separating with a period, just wrap the string in brackets. And you can pass a variable in the brackets.

```
let artist = "deecracks";
console.log(data[artist][0]["layercodename"])
```

```js
let data = {
  "deecracks": [{
      "layercodename": "osm",
      "layername": "Open Street Map",
    },
    {
      "layercodename": "olen",
      "layername": "tracks",
    }
  ],

  "theboomtownrats": [{
      "layercodename": "kuku",
      "layername": "Open Street Map",
    },
    {
      "layercodename": "olen",
      "pathto": "rerere.json",
    }
  ]
}

let artist = "deecracks";
console.log(data[artist][0]["layercodename"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the bracket notation. Like this:

```
var artist = 'theboomtownrats';
var megatest = data[artist][0].layercodename;
```

Comment: **theboomtownrats** would cause an error as its being passed as a variable and not string

Comment: Thanks. The answer has been updated.

Comment: Thank you, this was very simple, i guessed.